# how to pass data between 2 views with the same controller

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a mobile version for my site. I have a main view with a table of jobs. On my desktop version I share data between views and modals fine but I cant seem to understand how to share from a view to another view. they both are on the same controller. I need to be able to populate the second view with all the properties of the object. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rsxrl1TIKD82vfoodw04?p=preview)

```
//Pass Data to view two
$scope.editJob = function () {
    $location.path('/editJob');
 };

view one
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td ng-click="editJob(employee)">{{employee.Address}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

view two

```
<input type="text" ng-model="FavoriteFood"/>
```

Comment: $scope.editJob = function (employee) {
        $scope.employee= employee;
        $location.path('/editJob');
    }    wouldnt be as simple as passing this to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the app's location the controller reloads, losing all of it's state.  So, you can either put the data you want shared in a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), or investigate an alternate way of switching views (maybe [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) or [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) for instance)